# Core Foundation equivalents for NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-foundation

I'm aware that NSUrl is bridged to CFUrl. What are the Core Foundation equivalents for `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` so I can do something with a CFUrl object using pure C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are not direct equivalents to `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` in Core Foundation, but you can use the lower-level CFHTTP functions in [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork).

For example,

```
CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault,
        requestMethod, myUrl, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
CFHTTPMessageSetBody(myRequest, bodyData);
CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(myRequest, headerField, value);

CFReadStreamRef myReadStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, myRequest);

CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream);

CFHTTPMessageRef myResponse = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(myReadStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);
```

Comment: Make sure to copy settings for SSL as well. See [this example](https://github.com/HermesApp/Hermes/blob/87786657513cc774d1626f96f08e55306290400b/Sources/URLConnection.m#L60-L95) for more information.